# create enum in actionscript 3 and compare

Tags: actionscript-3, enums, flash-builder

I need to create some enum values, give it a default value and then compare it.

I have this enum class

```
public class Car
{
    public static const Tesla:int = 1;
    public static const Ford:int = 2;
}
```

How do I initiate a new Car enumn variable with a default value of "Tesla" and how do I compare the variable? I'm looking for something like this:

```
public var c:Car = new Car(Car.Tesla);

if (c == Car.Tesla){
// Do something
}
```

Edit, it is now changed to the following:

```
public final class Car
{

    public static const Tesla:String = "tesla";
    public static const Ford:String = "ford";

}
```

And in the mxml file:

```
    public var c:String = Car.Tesla;

    if (c == Car.Tesla){
        // Do something
    }
```

Comment: You can define a Car class member "type" and compare it to the constant: `if (c.type == Car.TESLA) { }`. Obviously, the constructor of Car will look somehow like this: `public function Car(typeProvided:int) { this.type = typeProvided; ... }`

Comment: Would you mind show me what I need to add to the class?

Comment: Can you post more of the mxml file? A `public var` declaration should be inside a class block whereas an `if` statement should be in a function. This setting both next to each other doesn't look correct.

Comment: I have the "var c:String = Car.Tesla; inside the <mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[ of the mxml file, and then I have the "if(ca == Car.Tesla){" inside the init functio of the mxml file and its on that line I get the error

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mxml. Could you please add the entire file to your question?

Answer (score 0):

> I have this enum class

Just so we're on the same page about it: that's not an enum and there are no enums in as3. The language doesn't have that feature.

> How do I initiate a new Car enumn variable with a default value of "Tesla" and how do I compare the variable?

You cannot, because `Car` is a type and the static properties it has are of type `int` which is something completely different.

What you can do is this:

```
var c:int = Car.Tesla;

if (c == Car.Tesla){
    // Do something
}
```

If you want to have a `Car` object instead, add a `brand` property to the class of type `int`, which you can then assign the value of your constants to:

```
var c:Car = new Car();
c.brand = Car.Tesla;

if (c.brand == Car.Tesla){
    // Do something
}
```

You could also add a parameter to the constructor and insert the value there.

Btw. changing

```
public static const Tesla:int = 1;
```

to

```
public static const Tesla:String = "tesla";
```

will give you the chance to get more meaningful values during debugging. The built in constants like `MouseEvent.CLICK` are defined this way.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to "public static const Tesla:String = "tesla";" and this...

  var c:String = Car.Tesla;
  
  if (c == Car.Tesla){
   // Do something
  }

But I get a "Access of undefined property" error on this line "if (c == Car.Tesla){"

Comment: @Magnus what property is undefined? How does your whole code look like? It looks like you have an unrelated scope problem. Please edit your question to include all relevant code, that is: the Car class and the full code that uses it.

Comment: I now got it working using this....

 public final class Car
 {
  
  public static const Tesla:String = "tesla";
  public static const Ford:String = "ford";
 
  public var type:String;
  
  public function Car(typeProvided:String = "") {
   this.type = typeProvided;
  }
  
 }

Comment: @Magnus but is this the desired design? It was unclear wether you want to have a whole object or not. There's no need to create this object if you only want to create a pseudo-enum of car brands.

Comment: I was looking for something like enum so that there wont be any typos when checking what type it is. I guess it work fine, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Magnus the first one described in my answer, just use an `int` (original question) or `String` variable on its own. No need to wrap it into an object